# MSSQL: Search for duplicates in columns based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a script that will look through the sql columns and search for duplicates based on first name, last name, and date of birth. Can you advice me how I can start this? Like I can do it for one id, but I need to go through the enter list of ids and do the search

```
id    Forename    Surname    DateofBirth
1     John          Doe      2015-05-16
2     Martin        Rocks    2015-04-18
3     John          Doe      2015-05-16
4     Ben           Dover    2014-08-09
```

So in this case, I just want to write a script that can take each ID and look for duplicates based on matching Forename, Surname and Date of birth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use analytical function to achieve your goal like this:

```
select * from (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Forename, Surname, DateofBirth order by ID) RN,
   Forename,
   Surname,
   DateofBirth
from table_name) x
where x.rn>1
```

Answer (score 1):

use corelated subquery

```
select t.* from table_name t where 
exists ( select 1 from table_name t1 where t1.DateofBirth=t.DateofBirth and t1.Forename=t.Forename
          and t1.surname=t.surname 
           group by t1.DateofBirth,t1.Forename,t1.Surname
           having count(*)>1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1  
              from table t1 
              where t1.Forename = t.Forename and t1.Surname = t.Surname and 
                    t1.DateofBirth = t.DateofBirth and t1.id <> t.id
             )
```